# How to get the project id when using project-scope authentication in openstack4j?

Tags: authentication, openstack

I'm using openstack4j to do project-scoped authenticatation.

```
os = OSFactory.builderV3()
     .endpoint("http://controller:5000/v3")
     .scopeToProject(Identifier.byId("1435221d37fd41699101bd739fe4375b"))  
     .credentials("admin", "openstack", Identifier.byName("default"))
     .authenticate();
```

This statement can be run correctly. **But my problem is: before authentication, how do I know the project id?**

So I changed another way to solve this question. First, I removed the `scopeToProject` method in above code and got a successfully unscoped authentication.

```
os = OSFactory.builderV3()
     .endpoint("http://controller:5000/v3") 
     .credentials("admin", "openstack", Identifier.byName("default"))
     .authenticate();
```

I can obtain the `userId = os.getToken().getUser().getId();`. But when I execute `os.identity().users().listUserProjects(userId)` to get the projects this user belongs to, the following exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.internal.DefaultEndpointURLResolver.resolveV3(DefaultEndpointURLResolver.java:120)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.internal.DefaultEndpointURLResolver.findURLV3(DefaultEndpointURLResolver.java:70)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSClientSession$OSClientSessionV3.getEndpoint(OSClientSession.java:388)
at org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpRequest$RequestBuilder.build(HttpRequest.java:405)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:192)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:187)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.v3.internal.UserServiceImpl.listUserProjects(UserServiceImpl.java:121)
...
```

This exception thrown at `token.getCatalog()`. Because the result of `getCatelog()` is null.

**NOTE**: I know in openstack dashboard login page, the user just need input the domain name, username, password and then the project information will returned after authentication. **This is exactly what I want.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned a default project for user `admin` using openstack dashboard, and now it works fine.